# ¿Cómo guardar con javascript una tabla de una vista ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Tengo una duda, tengo el siguiente código para generar una tabla `html` usando MVC con `.NET.` El siguiente es el código de la vista que genera la tabla.

```
<div id="no-more-tables">
    <table id="CarteraClients"  style="width: 100%;">
        <thead>
            <tr>

                <th scope="col" id="col1" width="55%">Cliente</th>
                <th scope="col" id="col2">Semana 1 </th>              
                <th scope="col" id="col2">Semana 2 </th>
                <th scope="col" id="col2">Semana 3 </th>  
                <th scope="col" id="col2">Semana 4 </th>
                <th scope="col" id="col2">Semana 5 </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @{

                if (Model.Count() == 0)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="4" class="error text-center"><small 
class="error">No hay elementos coincidentes.</small></th>
                    </tr>
                }
                else
                {
                    foreach (var item in Model)
                    { 
                        <tr>

                            <td data-title="Razon Social">
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => 
item.razon_social)
                            </td>
                            <td data-title="Semana 1" id="Semana1" 
class="row1">@Html.CheckBox("chkSemana1", false)</td>
                            <td data-title="Semana 2" id="Semana2" 
 class="row1">@Html.CheckBox("chkSemana2", false)</td>                           
                            <td data-title="Semana 3" id="Semana3" class="row1">@Html.CheckBox("chkSemana3", false)</td>
                            <td data-title="Semana 4" id="Semana4" class="row1">@Html.CheckBox("chkSemana4", false)</td>
                            <td data-title="Semana 5" id="Semana5" class="row1">@Html.CheckBox("chkSemana5", false)</td>
                       </tr>

                    }
                }
            }
        </tbody>

    </table>

    <button type="button" class="small" onclick="llenardata()"><img src="~/Content/img/magnifying-glass-8x.png" alt="Buscar" width="16" height="16" /> Guardar cartera</button>
</div>
```

Lo que quiero  hacer es guardar dentro de una tabla los clientes y el resultado del check por semana1, semana2, semana3, semana4, semana5.

Para esto, intento generar un objeto que me genere vía javascript una lista(cliente, semana[1..5])

Intente hacerlo via javascript pero no logro guardar el check. Mi código en javascript es el siguiente:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function llenardata() {
        var cant = 0;
        var tabla = document.getElementById("CarteraClients");
        var rowLength = 
 document.getElementById("CarteraClients").rows[0].cells.length;
        var tablaresultados = [];
        for (i = 0; i < tabla.rows.length; i++) {

            var ocells = tabla.rows.item(i).cells;
             var cellLength = ocells.length;


                var cliente = ocells.item(0).innerText;
                var semana1 = ocells.item(1).innerText;
                var semana2 = ocells.item(2).innerText;
                var semana3 = ocells.item(3).innerText;
                var semana4 = ocells.item(4).innerText;
                var semana5 = ocells.item(5).innerText;

                tablaresultados.push(cliente);
                //tablaresultados.push(semana1);
                //tablaresultados.push(semana2);
                //tablaresultados.push(semana3);
                //tablaresultados.push(semana4);
                //tablaresultados.push(semana5);

        }
        console.log(tablaresultados);
        $.ajax({
            url: url("IngresoProyeccion") + 'GuardarCarteraCliente',

            data:
                'IdUser=' + delegado +
                '&Ano=' + anyos +
                '&Mes=' + meses +
                '&Oportunidad= Levantamiento de Oportunidades'+  
                '&Cartera='+tablaresultados,

            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',

        }).success(function (html) {

            DesbloquearPantalla();
            $("#divReporte").html(html);
            //$("body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 'fast');
        });


    }
</script>
```

Lo que logro hacer es guardar mi listado de clientes, pero no logro guardar los `boolean` que hacen los usuarios al guardar.

Me gustaría saber si hay alguna idea de como realizar esto de manera eficiente.
O solo vía javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que la manera en que estas recuperando el valor de los checkbox es incorrecta.
Intenta con algo como

```
var semana1 = $("#chkSemana1").is(':checked');
var semana2 = $("#chkSemana2").is(':checked');
var semana3 = $("#chkSemana3").is(':checked');
```

ahora, la manera de enviar los datos al servidor sería almacenando estos valores en un array y posteriormente serializarlo.

```
var checks = new Array();
checks.push(semana1);
checks.push(semana2);
checks.push(semana3);
```

De igual manera, estas enviando los datos de forma incorrecta al servidor.
La llamada ajax quedaría mas o  menos de la sig. manera:

```
 $.ajax({
            url: url("IngresoProyeccion") + 'GuardarCarteraCliente',

            data:{
                'IdUser': delegado,
                'Ano': anyos,
                'Mes': meses,
                'Oportunidad': 'Levantamiento de Oportunidades',
                'Cartera': tablaresultados,
                'Checks': JSON.stringify(checks)
             }
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',

        }).success(function (html) {

            DesbloquearPantalla();
            $("#divReporte").html(html);
            //$("body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 'fast');
        });
```